# Rails 3 default host for _path helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Is there a way to set default host other than whats being shown in address bar? I am not talking about _url helpers , i want to do this for _path

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because `_path` omits the host completely. E.g. `users_path` does **NOT** produce:

```
http://www.domain.com/users/index
```

It produces:

```
/users/index
```

There is no way to set the host.

Comment: use base attribute in html to overcome this problem

Comment: ^ Awesome comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp - `tag('base', href: Rails.env.production? ? 'http://mysite.com' : 'http://mysite.com:3000')`